# vb net lock topmost form when program running

Tags: vb.net

I had a button in my form1,when when I click it,then form2 will show at topmost..
Now I want to lock the form2 ,user cannot click on form 1 until user click on the button OK in form2 then proceed to form3.

Can anyone teach me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [model form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w2h2y4y.aspx).

You can use [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) function to display modal form.

Comment: I used form2.ShowDialog(), but when proceed to form3,the data of form3 are are gone

Comment: If you are always doing new Form3, then it will happen. You need to either pass all the data/state into constructor, or keep the same instance to preserve data.